# Copy an empty deque

Tags: python

I'd like an efficient way to create several empty deques. How can I do this in Python? My first thought was to do something like this:

```
import collections

i = j = k = l = collections.deque()
```

This code simply creates multiple variables that reference the same deque. How I can quickly create several empty deques?

Comment: Why be eager? How about just `defaultdict(deque)`?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski `from collections import deque as dequeue` :P

Comment: What's your actual problem? This smells like vastly premature optimization as stated.

Comment: @TylerEaves: I think (or maybe just hope?) that by "quickly" the OP just meant "without repeating myself and typing a bunch of code", not "while cutting down at least 5% of the 14us of CPU time".

Comment: I agree with Tyler: if we knew why the OP wanted to have four double-ended queues we would probably be able to propose a better solution. *Four* is suspicious because it violates the [zero one infinity rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule).

Comment: I love this kind of question because it shows that even in Python's *There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.* there are lots of not-obviously-wrong ways to do a thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a generator expression:

```
i, j, k, l = (collections.deque() for _ in xrange(4))
```

Comment: It's a little odd to use `xrange` in place of `range` just to avoid creating an unnecessary list of 4 integers, but then use it in a list comprehension instead of a generator expression to create an unnecessary list of 4 deques…

Comment: `i,j,k,l=map(deque,[[]]*4)` </troll_golf>

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to beat the simple solution. 4 deque objects need to be created and they each need to be assigned to variables. You seem to just want to avoid a couple of new lines, but they don't change the efficiency of the code.

```
from collections import deque

i = deque()
j = deque()
k = deque()
l = deque()
```